# How to change label text in nativescript angular2

Tags: typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I don't know how to change the label text dynamically. When I'm clicking on the second tab position, it is triggering `onIndexChanged(args)` and printing the `console.log("One" +"Test");` in command prompt. But it doesn't change the text.

**first.page.html:**

```
<ActionBar title="Dashboard" class="action-bar">

   <Label [text]="'times'" textWrap="true"></Label>

</ActionBar>
```

**first.page.ts:**

```
export class FirstPage {


  public times = "Ratings";

 ....
   public onIndexChanged(args) {

        let tabView = <TabView>args.object;

       if(tabView.selectedIndex == 1){

            console.log("One" +"Test");

             this.times  = "Ratings";

       }


    }


  }
```

Comment: why not bind the label to a variable and change the variable instead of the label itself?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I'm new to nativescript.can't get you. can you post as an answer?

Comment: you're using angular, arent you?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon yes angular2

Answer (score 2):

html:

```
<ActionBar title="Dashboard" class="action-bar">
    <Label [text]="labelText" textWrap="true"></Label>
</ActionBar>
<StackLayout>
    <Button text="click me" (tap)="changeText()"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

ts:

```
export class FirstPage {
    labelText: string = "Times";
    changeText() {
        this.labelText = "Ratings";
    }
}
```

That should do the trick, the button is only there to see the change, you could do the call however you wanted to.

--EDIT--

swap `<Label [text]="labelText" textWrap="true"></Label>` with `<Label text="{{ labelText }}" textWrap="true"></Label>`

Comment: Its not changing the text.still it is showing text `Times` only.please check my edited post [here](https://www.pastiebin.com/5936821d986fd)

Comment: same thing I did like that.But its not changing the text.

Comment: @Stephen: You may have the problem that your `this.times = ` assignment is not called with the correct `this` reference? E.g. if `onIndexChanged` is already called with `this´ set to something which is not `FirstPage`. The solution from @mast3rd3mon seems correct.

Comment: Your solution is working good for 0th position in tab bar.Because when I'm entering into this page, by default it is calling 0th tab position.So its changing text. But when I'm moving to second or third tab, it's not changing the text. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Matthias247 his solution is working good for 0th position in tab bar.Because when I'm entering into this page, by default it is calling 0th tab position.So its changing text. But when I'm moving to second or third tab, it's not changing the text. Any suggestion?

Comment: having the `onIndexChanged()` method outside the class means it wont ever change the text, you need it inside your class

Comment: oh sorry.in stackoverflow post only I placed method outside.that's not an issue.In coding, I placed correctly.

Comment: ah ok, did you change the html like in my post?

Comment: I changed like this : `<Label text="{{ labelText }}" textWrap="true"></Label>`